# how would you describe the range of T, space of $2\times 2$ real matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

hope you can help me, I've got stuck on this, I'm really new to linear algebra.

Let $V$ be the set of complex numbers regarded as a vector space over the
field of real numbers. We define a function $T$ from $V$ into the space
of $2 \times 2$ real matrices, as follows. If $z = x + iy$ with $x$ and $y$ real numbers, then.
$$T(z) =\begin{bmatrix}
x + 7y & 5y\\
-10y & x-7y
\end{bmatrix}$$
the main question is:
How would you describe the range of T?

thanks!, Cheers.

Comment: A 2-dimensional subspace in the 4-dimensional space of real $2\times2$ matrices?  Maybe by means of a basis like $\left[\matrix{1&0\\0&1}\right]$ and $\left[\matrix{7&5\\-10&-7}\right]$?  You'd say that the range of $T$ is the span of those two vectors.  Not sure there is one uniform way to describe subspaces, but bases should be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\Bbb R$-linear map $T:\Bbb C\to M_2(\Bbb R)$ is defined by
$$
T(x+yi)=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
x + 7 \, y & 5 \, y \\
-10 \, y & x - 7 \, y
\end{array}\right]
=
x\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
+y
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
7 & 5 \\
-10 & -7
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T)=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
7 & 5 \\
-10 & -7
\end{array}\right]
\right\}
$$
Since these two matrices are linearly independent (do you see why?) we say that the image of $T$ is two dimensional with these two matrices forming a basis.

Comment: two matrices are linearly independent when the unique combination that would give us the matrix zero is the trivial (using zeros as scalars).